# What is the [plm] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [plm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plm) tag has no tag wiki, no explanation. What is it for?  I would like to add an tag wiki, but need first to know why it is there.

Comment: I added a (brief) wiki.

Comment: One infers the meaning of a tag by seeing what questions it's used on. Indeed with acronyms, even if you're quite sure you know what it means, it's often important to check what people use it for, because many abbreviations have more than one meaning in stats (GLM apparently has at least three, now; LDA has at least four, or if we also count actuarial applications, possibly six). Where possible we should disambiguate ones where more than one interpretation is widely used for the tag (say by generating two new tags that spell things out then retagging, and so on).

Comment: @Glen_b This overloading of terminology appears to suggest that acronyms-as-tags is an ambiguous way to go about sorting questions. Is it really a great idea to use [plm] (and [glm] and [lda]) instead of a more descriptive term?

Comment: Yes, we should clean up and choose more descriptive terms!

Comment: @user777 We might be able to make an argument for retaining glm for generalized linear model (by sheer numerical superiority), but perhaps we could discuss whether lda is better expanded; latent dirichlet analysis vs linear discriminant analysis is the main competition for that TLA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's used in only 25 questions at the time of writing; the few I looked at all make reference to R's [`plm` Linear models for panel data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/index.html) package.

Recall that anyone with over a certain reputation can create new tags—we can write tag wikis without worrying about their original motivation.